# Declare project wide variable in Objective C

Tags: ios, appdelegate

I was wondering if there is a way to declare a project wide variable like you get when you start a application with a UINavigationController and you can call that navigation controller from anywhere in you application because of how its been declared in the applications Delegate.

I am wanting to create a project (global) var that allows me to call SVProgress hud or dismiss it from anywhere in my application. I have this issue where I load a UIViewController onto the navigation stack, start the SVProgress hud then make a request to my DB.. if I get an error back i need to handle a few things one of them is to be able to dissmiss the SVProgress hud.

This is the code I have so far

AppDelegate.h

```
#import "SVProgressHUD.h"

@interface MYAPPAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate> {
//..
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) SVProgressHUD *svprogressHud;
```

AppDelegate.m

```
@synthesize svprogressHud;
```

not really sure if this is possible hopefully someone out there will be able to help me out.

Here is a [link](https://github.com/samvermette/SVProgressHUD) to SVProgress git

Comment: Side note - assuming you are using the latest compiler (the default with the last couple versions of Xcode), you do not need the `@synthesize` line. Just having the `@property` is enough. No ivar, no synthesize needed.

Comment: man im gonna have to go through and clean up so much stuff LOL thanks for that though, I will read up on it.

Comment: Either put the var in your AppDelegate or make it a static.  Or you can create a "singleton" for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you can do from your view controller is grab the app delegate and cast it to the type of your delegate like so:

```
#import "MYAPPDelegate.h"
MYAPPDelegate *ad = (MYAPPDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[ad.svprogressHud displayOrWhatever];
```

Not really the cleanest but should get the job done.

Comment: would it be possible to do this in a NSObject class also?

Comment: The above code should work from any Objective-C class compiled with your project (you'll need to `#import` your app delegate header).

Comment: The reason I ask this, I might not have been clear enough in my questoin but I would like to be able to declare the SVProgress hud to show in a view controller then later in a NSObject class i would like to be able to dissmiss it.

Comment: @HurkNburkS you'll definitely be able to access this global variable from both the `NSObject` subclass and your view controller.

Comment: okay going to give it ago now :) sorry for the late reply but will mark your answer correct once I have done it :)

Comment: You know, it never occurred to me that someone might not know that the AppDelegate is accessible from anywhere in the app.

Comment: weird. for some reason I cannot access the SVProgressHud methods..., I have declared the SVProgressHud in the appdelegate, but I cannot use the methods of the SVProgressHud methods outside of the appdelegate.

Comment: @HurkNburkS - What do you mean "cannot access"?  What error do you get??

Comment: no error, but SVProgressHUD is an NSObject class with methods in it etc. So when I declare my SVProgressHUD object in the app delegate in there i can call [svprogressHUD methodname] but when I then try to access the AppDelegate to use the svProgressHud i dont have access to the methods SVProgressHUD Object has in it...

Answer (score 2):

Just add the header file name into you pre-compiled header (`<projectname>_Prefix.pch`) file inside of the `#ifdef __OBJC__`

Like as:

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import "SVProgressHUD.h"
#endif
```

Then it will give you access to the file across all files.....

Comment: okay cool that is one of the requierments but the other is that if I create an instance of SVProgressHud to load in a UIViewController then I want to be able to unload that same SVProgressHud from say another view of a nsobject class... the problem i am having now is that i am creating multiple instances of svprogresshud so if i load it in one viewcontroller i have to go back to that same viewcontroller to unload it.

Comment: Then just put two methods, one for load SVProgressHud and another for unload SVProgressHud. Just create the instance and called these method whenever you need them..

Answer (score 1):

Just extending Roberts answer, In order to avoid repeating the code to get the app delegate and then cast it into MYAPPDelegate, I would create a header file/class in your project with a utility function.

Create new header called `AppUtils.h`

```
#import "MYAPPAppDelegate.h"
#ifndef AppName_AppUtils_h
#define AppName_AppUtils_h

static inline MYAPPAppDelegate* AppDelegate() {
    return (MYAPPDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
}

#endif
```

Where ever you need access to these variables import the header `AppUtils.h` and use the helper function. Example:

```
#import "AppUtils.h"

...

- (void)foo {
    // use app delegate
    UIViewController *rootVC = AppDelegate().rootViewController;
}
```

Comment: Or you can just `#define` that expression.

Comment: Stylistic choice. I usually like static inline's instead of #defines. You can set breakpoints/add logging etc much easier. #define's are ok though.

Comment: not sure if this will work for my problem. SVProgressHUD is a object class  and for some reason if i declare it in my AppDelegate then try to access it from another class i cannot access the SVProgressHUD class methods... I'm not 100% sure why.

Comment: Generally it's not necessary to have the `#ifndef` stuff in an Objective-C h file.  Only needed if the file will be included in a pure C/C++ file.